# Best structure for multi-modules maven project

Tags: maven

I would like to know if there is a best way to group maven projects.

If I have more than 1 pom project, how is the best way to set them?

```
Solution 1:
groupid:parent:version (pom)
    groupid.parent:child:version (jar)
    groupid.parent:subproject:version (pom)
        groupid.parent.subproject:childOne:version (jar)
        groupid.parent.subproject:childTwo:version (jar)
        groupid.parent.subproject:childThree:version (jar)

Solution 2:
groupid:parent:version (pom)
    groupid:parent-child:version (jar)
    groupid:parent-subproject:version (pom)
        groupid:parent-subproject-childOne:version (jar)
        groupid:parent-subproject-childTwo:version (jar)
        groupid:parent-subproject-childThree:version (jar)
```

Any other options?!?

Comment: This heavily depends on your needs. Some criteria are: are modules release independently or are they release together? Are submodule groups being released together? I would say there is no "best" structure that applies to all projects. Maybe you can be a bit more specific what your criteria are?

Comment: I am looking for a general solution. For all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm preferential to the module organization described in *Solution 1*.  Notice with this approach that you could encounter (or anticipate) some naming collisions...which are politely mitigated by most Maven plugins.  For example:

- You have a global library in your Maven ecosystem named *some.groupId:service:1.0.0*
- And then inside one of your Maven multi-module projects, an artefact named *another.groupId:service:1.0.0*

Now pretend you have a Maven web application module that depends on both of the afore mentioned *service* artefacts.  When the maven-war-plugin copies the dependencies to the WEB-INF/lib directory, it is smart enough to discover the *service* jar filename collisions and renames each jar to include their groupId.

I know that was a lot of extra information, but some people are not aware of this bit of Maven war intelligence...

Comment: Yes! It is one of common problems I have. tks